# Speech software for Windows

Tags: windows, speech-recognition

I'm looking for some software that would allow me to convert my voice into text. This would really help because it hurts my hands to type.

I would like to be able to open applications, my web browser, microsoft Word, microsoft Excel, etc., all with my voice. I would also like to be able to type with my voice within these applications. For example, I would like to be able to open Microsoft Word, type a document all in Microsoft Word as well as open Microsoft Word itself with my voice. For another example, I would also like to be able to open gmail, type an email, correctly format said email, all with my voice.

I am using Windows 10, and have tried to do all of this with windows speech recognition. Let's be honest windows speech sucks. It is highly inaccurate and gets all of my words wrong.

Any recommendations on voice recognition software? It would be nice to have something that is free and downloadable online. Maybe there is an extension or something?

Comment: "... nice to have something that is free and downloadable..." is generally read as a preference rather than a constraint. Are you willing to use commercial software? If so, how much are you willing to spend? What research have you done, and what possible solutions other than the basic Windows Speech Recognition have you rejected and why?

Comment: i am not willing to spend a lot, i am sure there is something free. I have researched and cant find anything. I cannot find anything....that is why I am here.

Comment: The reason I asked about your research and your budget is because a commercial package, Dragon Naturally Speaking, is generally well-thought-of for speech-to-text - although, like all speech-to-text packages, it will require training.

Comment: ok i will check it out

Answer (score 1):

One can use Dragon Professional Individual (formerly known as Dragon Naturally Speaking):

- Non-free
- Works on Microsoft Windows 10
- Countless of small bugs but that's the best I'm aware of on Windows. I use it daily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit off-topic but it is also free of charge:

You can speak into your mobile phone, speech recognition is really good (and free) there. Then upload the textfile to a shared folder (Cloud, dropbox, Windows ...) for further editing.

Optionally, if you had a Chromebook you could use that to dictate into, say, Excel (using Excel App for Android), and then edit the file right there on the Chromebook, and later upload to a shared folder, and continue editing on Windows.